# Mapping objects

Tags: c#, .net

Does anyone know about any third party .NET libraries which could map objects between different layers of a project like view and model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Subsonic if you want to interact with a db